# 'Await' doesn't work with imported Async Function (email-deep-validator)

Tags: node.js, async-await, requirejs

I'm trying to use the 'email-deep-validator' npm package ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-deep-validator ) following the examples:

```
const EmailValidator = require('email-deep-validator');
const emailValidator = new EmailValidator();
const { wellFormed, validDomain, validMailbox } = await emailValidator.verify('myEmail@myDomain.com');
```

But Node returns this error: *SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function*

I've checked in the code of this package that the ***verify*** function is defined like *Async* ( https://github.com/getconversio/email-deep-validator/blob/master/lib/index.js ) and I tried to execute the code with serveral versions of Node (9.2.0, 10.16.1, 12.7.0).

I'd appreciate an orientation. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that the function is marked as `async` means that it can use `await` internally, it makes no difference to the function’s external API. Whenever you want to use `await` you’ll have to put that code in a function that you mark as `async`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `await` inside `async` functions.

```
const EmailValidator = require('email-deep-validator');
const emailValidator = new EmailValidator();

// top level async function
(async () => {
  const { wellFormed, validDomain, validMailbox } = await emailValidator.verify('myEmail@myDomain.com');
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use await only in async function, the error message is pretty clear.

Example:

```
const EmailValidator = require('email-deep-validator');
const emailValidator = new EmailValidator();

async function main() {
  const { wellFormed, validDomain, validMailbox } = await emailValidator.verify('myEmail@myDomain.com');
  // ...rest of your code
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank at all for your help. This and other answers works properly:

[@Rashomon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6546440/rashomon):

You can use await only in async function, the error message is pretty clear.

Example:

```
const EmailValidator = require('email-deep-validator');
const emailValidator = new EmailValidator();

async function main() {
  const { wellFormed, validDomain, validMailbox } = await emailValidator.verify('myEmail@myDomain.com');
  // ...rest of your code
}

main()
```